# Дать леща - откуда выражение?

Tags: этимология

Как мы все знаем, лещ - это такая круглая озерная рыба. А еще есть выражение "дать леща" - то есть, хлопнуть ладонью, например, по шее.
Вот хотелось бы узнать, во-первых, происхождение названия рыбы, а во-вторых, при чем тут эта рыба к драке? (Мне так и представляется, как кого-то лупят по шее большой мокрой рыбой))))

Comment: @Lin, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

К рыбе отношения не имеет.

Словарь Михельсона говорит, что был такой глагол лещить - колоть, раскалывать, обычно камень - производить лескъ (Ср. Лескать, ляскать — хлестать).От него лескъ, лещ - удар со всего размаху, сопровождающийся звуком, как от бича.

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/michelson_old/1984/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B9

Answer (score -1):

если от души влупить, то фиолетовый отпечаток ладони очень сильно напоминает форму леща...